# How to print H1 instead of H2 for Panel

Tags: 7, panels

This is the template currently being used:

panels-pane.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($pane_prefix): ?>
  <?php print $pane_prefix; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $id; ?> <?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if ($admin_links): ?>
    <?php print $admin_links; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <<?php print $title_heading; ?><?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
      <?php print $title; ?>
    </<?php print $title_heading; ?>>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php if ($feeds): ?>
    <div class="feed">
      <?php print $feeds; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="pane-content">
    <?php print render($content); ?>
  </div>

  <?php if ($links): ?>
    <div class="links">
      <?php print $links; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($more): ?>
    <div class="more-link">
      <?php print $more; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if ($pane_suffix): ?>
  <?php print $pane_suffix; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The variable `$title_heading` is h2. It comes in `$content`

panels.module

```
  $vars['title_heading'] = !empty($content->title_heading) ? $content->title_heading : variable_get('override_title_heading', 'h2');
```

However, I see no way of supplying it, and cannot create it in my Fieldable Pane Panel:

[image]

If I try to add a field, it comes with the `field_` prefix, and I just need a plain `title_heading`.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Enable debug theme to see what suggestion you can use for  this specific page, instead of `panels-pane.tpl.php`

Comment: Can you show the Manage Display tab?  I don't have a D7 site handy to check, but I think it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is intended for Node title not Fieldable Panels Panes as per the screenshot  below:

[image]

Your best option is to override the `panels-pane.tpl` according to theme suggestions for your target pane and manually add the `<h1>` tag in place of the `$title_heading` variable.
It might not be an elegant solution but it works!